# Чтение и доступ к  бинарным данным в файле

Tags: perl, linux

Добрый день,

Всю жизнь пользовался perlом для обработки текста и для web, а сейчас возникла задача распотрошить бинарный файл. Опыта в этом никакого, кроме некоторый мутной теории, посему прошу помощь зала.

Есть бинарный файл, формат его мне известен, надо прочитать заголовок и затем уже сам контент. Вот, к примеру, первые 64 байта

```
0000000 8991 1998 0044 0000 0003 0000 000a 0000
0000010 0004 0000 0100 0000 3edf 0046 0000 0000
```

Первые два байта это, допустим, `size`. Затем 2 байта - это `Count`,  затем 6 байт - `Something`. Хочу сделать хеш `%header`, и в него положить в виде `$header{'Size'}`, `$header{'Count'}` и т.д.

Как правильно это хранить, и как правильно вообще читать?

Answer (score 4):

Смотреть надо в сторону функций `pack` и `unpack`

```
@$header{'Size','Count'} = unpack('ss',$binary_str);
```

Comment: точно... unpack ('s')!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [Objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump)